# Why does look_down method in HTML::Element fail to find <section> elements?

Tags: perl, html-treebuilder

The code below shows that TreeBuilder method look_down cannot find the "section" element.  Why?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html =<<'END_HTML';
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<div attrname="div">
<section attrname="section">
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
END_HTML

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);

my @divs = $tree->look_down('attrname', 'div');
print "number of div elements found = ", scalar(@divs), "\n";

my @sections = $tree->look_down('attrname', 'section');
print "number of section elements found = ", scalar(@sections), "\n";

$tree->delete();
```

Output:
    number of div elements found = 1
    number of section elements found = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->ignore_unknown(0);  # <-- Include unknown elements in tree
$tree->parse($html);
my @divs = $tree->look_down('attrname', 'div');
my @sections = $tree->look_down('attrname', 'section');
print "number of div elements found = ", scalar(@divs), "\n";
print "number of section elements found = ", scalar(@sections), "\n";
```

**Output**:

```
number of div elements found = 1
number of section elements found = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Hakon.  You are right that it seems the problem is that <section> is regarded as an unknown tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @divs = $tree->look_down('attrname', 'div');
print "number of div elements found = ", scalar(@divs), "\n";
```

This found one element because it matched the ***attribute*** `attrname` with value `div` that happened to be on `<div>` tag.

```
my @sections = $tree->look_down('attrname', 'section');
print "number of section elements found = ", scalar(@sections), "\n";
```

This matches nothing because there's no tag with an attribute named `attrname` with value `section`.

They should be

```
my @divs = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'div');
...
my @sections = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'section');
```

This is all somewhat obtusely explained in the [HTML::Element#lookdown](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element#look_down) documentation.  There's no clear explanation of what a "criteria" is, and you'd have to read the entire page to find the pseudo-attribute `_tag` to refer to the tag name... but then carefully reading the entire page would probably save you hours of frustration in the long run :-)

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I will read thru the documentation fully.   But I also tried find("section") method as well, which also found nothing.   So it appears that "section" is not regarded as a valid tag?   And <section attrname="section"> is not regarded as an element.   Sorry for my lack of understanding on HTML basics.